# Piratunbu theme 2.0 for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, themes, customization

I would really love to have this theme but can't seem to find where to get it from. Does anyone have it or know how to get it for 12.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link to download Piratunbu theme for Ubuntu 12.04.

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=147063

Download the theme from here, and don't forget to read "readme" file inside the package. "readme" will help you to install the theme properly.